# Sharp Image rotation during resizing

Tags: javascript, node.js, sharp

This image rotates during resizing even after adding `.rotate()` and `.withMetadata()` to sharp pipline.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that methods in order

```
  .withMetadata()`
  .resize(width, height)
```